# JQuery.Datatable error: Unhandled exception at line 5485, column 5 in dataTables.js 0x80070057 - htmlfile: Invalid argument

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, datatable

Friends, Today while working with jQuery datatable, I came across an error stating the following:

> Unhandled exception at line 5485, column 5 in  jquery.dataTables.js 0x80070057 -
>   htmlfile: Invalid argument.

at

```
if ( !bRemove && oSettings.nTableReinsertBefore )
        {
            nOrig.insertBefore( oSettings.nTable, oSettings.nTableReinsertBefore );
        }
```

in jquery.dataTables.js

The point is I never encounter this problem in either Chrome or Firefox except in IE8.

My markup on the view was:

```
 `<table id="Results">  

  </table>`
```

After hours of wastage of time, I came to know from [this post](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/6694/ie8-fndestroy-datatables-1-8-2-jquery-1-6-2/p1) that we should enclose our table(to which datatable theme is applied) in a `<div></div>`.

And this error has gone after this simple trick. I believe it would help someone like me.

But I would really appreciate if somebody can tell me

> WHY THIS HAPPENS IN ONLY IE(8)..?

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the question and answer. Enclosing table in a div fixed the  problem for me as well.